# Rotate(90deg) not being applied using .transform in Chrome 37

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, transform

I have some code that, until recently, worked on all browsers supporting CSS transforms. It broke in the newest Chrome (37). I found the issue. The transform from the computed style of an element is not accepted by other elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<span></span>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
}

.one {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.two {
    background-color: blue
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var oneStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.one'));
var oneTransform = oneStyle.transform;
document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = 'Tranform value is: ' + oneTransform;
var twoStyle = document.querySelector('.two').style;
twoStyle.transform = oneTransform;
```

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/0v8v2xd7/

The issue is that the second (blue) element does not rotate the same as the first (red) element is even though I told it to in the javascript.

This looks like a bug to me. Is it?

**EDIT:** My actual code was working in every browser but the newest Chrome, but it appears my sample code breaks in all browsers. I'd still like to understand why the above problem occurs.

**EDIT 2:** Got it to break in only Chrome 37 again. My guess is that it doesn't like the scientific notation; but then why would the computed style have it?

Comment: Interesting - using a value of 45deg seems to work.  A value of 90deg fails: [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v8v2xd7/4/)

Comment: BTW: the new code above fails on Safari Version 7.0.6 (9537.78.2) - you need to use the property `webkitTransform` rather than `transform`

Comment: doesn't chrome also use webkit?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Nope, Chrome doesn't [require the -webkit extension](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). You can also reproduce this issue by tweaking the element in the dev console. It rejects the style, but only for some values.

Comment: i realize that chrome doesn't require the extension, but the rendering engine is the same, isn't it?

Comment: 176deg also fails, even though the computed style *does not* contain scientific notation.

Comment: Funny! `rotate(89.999deg)` works: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/0v8v2xd7/10/

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Older versions of Chrome needed the `-webkit-` prefix, the current one does not. On versions of Chrome that accept both I *think* they use the same rendering no matter which prefix (or lack there of) they are accepting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem, similar errors happen with older versions of Chrome and other vendors as well.

The usual fix is, as Hashem [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690711/strange-transform-behavior-in-chrome-37-is-this-a-bug#comment40154185_25690711) partly, to either change the rotation to something like `89.9deg` or force GPU rendering by doing something like `translateZ(1px)` in addition to the rotation. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/0v8v2xd7/16/). In the future we can likely force this as well by using the [`will-change`](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-css-will-change-property) property

This is because browsers have trouble rendering certain things and rendering elements rotated exactly 90 degrees is one of those things. Sometimes they need a little help :)

Comment: Can you explain why this causes the browser to simply give up. Based on what you said, I would have expected it to render with aliasing instead of doing nothing at all.

Comment: It's just something that is common with Chrome that they don't fix. There's no really good way to explain it without seeing the source code most likely